# Is there a way to implement numpy's methods with normal lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm trying to implement a class that break a big numpy array into a list of *n* arrays. The thing is that it is hard to work with really big arrays because of space, so what I was trying to do is literally split them into lists. As a list is more flexible in the way it is stored.

What I currently have is a class that is already doing part of it's trick:

```py
class Array_list:
  data = list()
  sliced = 0

  def __init__(self, new_list = None):
    self.data = [new_list] if ( type(new_list) == type(list()) ) else list()
    self.sliced = 0
  
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    self.data[index // self.sliced][index % self.sliced]

  def __str__(self):
    return self.data.__str__()

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.data.__repr__()

  def slice(self, n):
    concat, output = [], []
    while (len(self.data) > 0):
      size = 0
      while ((size < n) and (len(self.data) > 0)):
        if (len(self.data[0]) <= (n - size)):
          concat.append(self.data[0])
          size += len(self.data[0])
          del self.data[0]
        else:
          concat.append(self.data[0][:(n - size)])
          size += len(self.data[0])
          self.data.insert(1, self.data[0][(n - size):])
          del self.data[0]
      output.append(np.concatenate(concat))
      concat = list()
    self.data = output
    self.sliced = n
```

The part I'm stuck at is dealing with numpy's features, mainly the column extractor and the sum, like this:

```py
arr = np.array([ [0, 1, 2],
                 [9, 8, 7] ])
print(arr[:, 0])
print(arr[:, [1, 0]])
print(arr + 5)
```

I need to use them in my main code, but I also am having the problem of too large arrays. Does anyone have any tip on what I can do or search for?

PS: I'm a begginer when it comes to Python and this also is my first question at Stack Overflow so any feedback on anything is very welcome

Comment: I do not understand the argument of space. List takes more space than Numpy's array for primitive types since they are packed in memory while CPython lists contains references to pure python object often allocated separately (which take far more space than just one int or one float). Thus it seems a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: @JérômeRichard What I mean by space is that while arrays must be allocated in continuous lines, lists can be allocated with their nodes at anywere of the memory. So in the case I've ran into I have some arrays that are too large to be stored like arrays, but when I try to store like lists it is possible. Of course working with lists is way to expensive talking about performance so that's why I wanted to use them like a list of arrays

Comment: Break your problem down into steps. Your premises are unclear and your implementation is likely flawed. There's too much to unpack in one question

Comment: @MadPhysicist Right. My problem is that I have to do operations with arrays, more specifically I am doing an implementation of a Hilbert's space filling curve generator. Implementing it with lists the solution works, but when I tryied to optimize with numpy's arrays it crashes at 13 iterations because there's not enough continuous space to allocate the array. What I am trying is to implement the arrays into lists because that way I can be able to workaround that issue. If it helps to understand there are the two versions of the code: https://codeshare.io/6ppALz, https://codeshare.io/9OOjD4

Comment: The simplest (usually) is to split the large array into chunks on one axis such as the first.  And then do iterations (list comprehensions) on that list as necessary.  Trying to recreate a large set of `numpy` in such as list is too much work.  Learning packages like `tensorflow` implement arrays as (batch, samples, features), and even have `lazy` iteration methods on the batch dimension, allowing them to work with datasets that are too big for memory (contiguous or not).

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you :). I'll study your ideas